# Is there a list of words that are known by all english speakers?

Tags: vocabulary, dictionaries, lists

Sometimes one finds a word he doesn't know .. but is there a list of words which could be memorized over several months maybe a list of words .. I don't need a short one or one with easy vocabs or repeated vocabs .. but also I don't want a huge list which has words which are not known by speakers ..

I think it's not 3000 words of oxford or else because lots of them are already known and there are words outside this list which are used also in language .. what do you suggest?

Comment: I don't think such a list exists or is possible.

Comment: When my daughter was less than a year old she, an English speaker, knew but one word.

Comment: I'm just asking for a suggestion I'm not asking if it exists or not .. and I've already mentioned an example in my question for this kind of lists ..

Comment: Not exactly the same thing, but here are the [100 most common words]( https://www.englishclub.com/vocabulary/common-words-100.htm)

Comment: lol are you kidding?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a silly question. Even with the list of the 1000 most common words, there's bound to be at least *one* "English speaker" who doesn't know at least one of them.

Comment: one of two things you didn't get the question or you didn't read the question

Comment: @DJ - Here was my first thought (granted, it's a smart-aleck answer): Yes, such a list exists. It's called a _dictionary_. :-)

Comment: @J.R. http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/words/weird-and-wonderful-words